# why does antlr for c# generate code throw non existentexception

Tags: antlr4

ANTLR4 4.7.1 generates a line in the parse.cs file that says

```
throw new RuntimeException("UNEXPECTED_CHAR=" + (_localctx._UNEXPECTED_CHAR!=null?_localctx._UNEXPECTED_CHAR.Text:null));
```

The exception doesnt exist. Its easy to fix by hand editing the generated code, but thats kind of annoying to have to do each iteration of grammer edit.

Using the built in c# support like this

```
java -jar c:\tools\antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp -visitor SQLite.g4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is not coming from ANTLR, it's coming from the grammar file you're using.

Assuming that you're using [SQLite.g4 from the grammars-v4 repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sqlite/SQLite.g4), the culprit is the `error` rule on lines 37-42:

```
error
 : UNEXPECTED_CHAR 
   { 
     throw new RuntimeException("UNEXPECTED_CHAR=" + $UNEXPECTED_CHAR.text); 
   }
;
```

So you can fix the problem by editing the grammar to either contain C# code instead of Java code or not contain any embedded code at all (it should be fine to just remove the `error` rule (and the one instance where it's used) altogether).